# Is it possible to pass member function (method) dependent on instance to STL's algorithm from another member function, directly?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I want to make something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Multiplier {
public:
    double multiply_by;

    double apply(double x) { return x * multiply_by; }

    std::vector<double> transform(const std::vector<double>& v) {
        std::vector<double> res;
        std::transform(begin(v), end(v), std::back_inserter(res), this::apply); // I have an error on this::apply
        return res;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<double> v{1,2,3,4,5};
    Multiplier multiplier{3};

    auto res = multiplier.transform(v);
}
```

I saw solutions with std::mem_fun() and std::bind2nd(), and I know workaround via lambda.

But does it exist a more convenient way to make this, possibly in last c++ standards?

(because answers that I saw about mem_fun were a little aged.)

Thanks.

Comment: Lambda is the "more convenient way"

Comment: Renaming `apply` in `operator()` might allow to just pass `*this` without binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, because a member function has a "hidden" parameter, which is the object that the method is being "called on".

So when you write:

```
Multipler m;
m.apply(1.0);
```

what's really going on is that `Multiplier::apply` is being called with two parameters: The object `m` (which you can refer to using the keyword `this`), and the double `x`.

`transform` wants something that is callable with a single parameter, and `Multiplier::apply` is not that.

`mem_fun`, etc allow you to create a function object that is callable with a single parameter by supplying the object earlier.